# Error: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var Form_addTurbo = $('form#Form_addTurbo');
    Form_addTurbo.submit(function (e){
        e.preventDefault;
        v = new Notification('Creating Turbo.', 'information', 'Working..', function(){return;});
        $.post('/api/turbos/new.php', {
            action : 'createNew'
        }, function (r){
            v.hide();
            if(r.success){
                new Notification('Turbo Create.', 'saved', '', function(){return;});
            }else if(r.error){

            }else{
                new Notification('Something went wrong.', 'error', '', function(){return;});
            }
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Which uses this api

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {$("body").prepend('<ul id="notifications"></ul>');});

/**
 * Global notification system
 *
 * @param  String      Message to be displayed
 * @param  String      Type of notification
 *
 * @author    Bram Jetten
 * @version    28-03-2011
 */
Notification.fn = Notification.prototype;

function Notification(value, type, tag, onclickfunc) {
  this.log(value, type);
  this.element = $('<li><span class="image '+ type +'"></span>' + value + '</li>');
  if(typeof tag !== "undefined" && tag !== '') {
    $(this.element).append('<span class="tag">' + tag + '</span>');
  }
  if(typeof onclickfunc == 'function'){
      this.element.click(onclickfunc);
  }
  $("#notifications").append(this.element);
  this.show();
}

/**
 * Show notification
 */
Notification.fn.show = function() {
  $(this.element).slideDown(200);
  $(this.element).click(this.hide);
}

/**
 * Hide notification
 */
Notification.fn.hide = function() {  
  $(this).animate({opacity: .01}, 200, function() {
    $(this).slideUp(200, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Log notification
 * 
 * @param  String      Message to be logged
 * @param  String      Type of notification
 */
Notification.fn.log = function(value, type) {
  switch(type) {
    case "information":
      console.info("*** " + value + " ***");
      break;
    case "success":
      console.log(value);
      break;
    case "warning":
      console.warn(value);
      break;
    case "error":
      console.error(value);
      break;
    case "saved":
      console.log(value);
      break;
    default:
      console.log(value);
      break;
  }
}
```

So what happens is that I try close the notification using the hide function that I believe it gives but I get this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

I believe it doesn't know what "this" is but how would I be able to get this to work.

Comment: Have you included jQuery JS file in your HTML `<head>` tag ? P.S. I didn't downvote ...

Comment: Can you create a test case, e.g. at http://jsfiddle.net/? Your error seems to be originated from the jQuery framework.

Comment: I have just created a jsfiddle URL http://jsfiddle.net/aF4TQ/1/ hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some minor changes to your example. Try it out http://jsfiddle.net/FLE39/

Had a closer look at your code and made a new jsfiddle. See updated link.

Comment: It still does not hide.
This is the new error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

That I found out is because of the $(this).remove();

Comment: This part `$("#notifications").append(this.element);` will not work until the DOM has finished loading and the #notifications elements has been added.

Comment: You don´t have to wrap all your functions with a `$(document).ready()` but the call to you function should be made once the DOM is ready :)

Comment: The notification message fades and slidesUp at click. What´s not working? Browser?

Comment: I am using Chrome, Yes it fade and hides on click but I want to be able to hide it using Javascript but it will not work. Which is why v.hide; is not inside any event listener I want to prompt this like a waiting notification and then after the wait is over I call v.hide; and then create another notification. But v.hide; doesn't work only when you click on it that it hides.

Comment: $(v.element).remove(); -- This does work though even though I would prefer to be able to use the v.hide.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this in backend node.js then this error comes up instead of html-to-image use node-html-to-image.